# Access Error "This Recordset is not Updatable" having SQL Server backend

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc

I have a form that displays a list of clients. The form contains 3 combo boxes and others are Text boxes. So when I add the tables to the query which contains the data that goes into the combo box, it doesn't work but when I remove the table the query becomes Updatable. I have attached the images of both the queries.

***Updatable Query***

```
SELECT [1-01_Clients_tbl].CNR, 
[FNC] & " " & [SNC] AS [Service User Full Name], 
[1-01_Clients_tbl].PT AS [Physiotherapist name (adjust)], 
[1-01_Clients_tbl].[PDS Score (txt)] AS [Score (txt)], 
[1-01_Clients_tbl].[PDS Score (nmbr)] AS [Score (No)],
[1-01_Clients_tbl].[Date for WLI],
[1-01_Clients_tbl].DOB AS [Date of Birth],
[1-01_Clients_tbl].TASCode,
[1-01_Clients_tbl].PTact AS [Active Status Physio Details (adjust)], 
[_Circular_Temp].ActiveStatus AS [Active Status APH]
FROM ([1-01_Clients_tbl] 
LEFT JOIN [1-01-Clients_TransferXtra_tbl] ON [1-01_Clients_tbl].CNR = [1-01-Clients_TransferXtra_tbl].CNR) 
LEFT JOIN _Circular_Temp ON [1-01_Clients_tbl].CNR = [_Circular_Temp].CNR
WHERE ((([1-01_Clients_tbl].CNR)<>1 Or ([1-01_Clients_tbl].CNR)=2) 
AND (([_Circular_Temp].ActiveStatus)="yes"));
```

***Non-Updatable Query***

```
SELECT [1-01_Clients_tbl].CNR, 
[FNC] & " " & [SNC] AS [Service User Full Name], 
[1-01_Clients_tbl].PT AS [Physiotherapist name (adjust)], 
[1-01_Clients_tbl].[PDS Score (txt)] AS [Score (txt)], 
[1-01_Clients_tbl].[PDS Score (nmbr)] AS [Score (No)], 
[1-01_Clients_tbl].[Date for WLI], 
[1-01_Clients_tbl].DOB AS [Date of Birth], 
[1-01_Clients_tbl].TASCode, 
[1-01_Clients_tbl].PTact AS [Active Status Physio Details (adjust)], 
[_Circular_Temp].ActiveStatus AS [Active Status APH], 
[5-10_TeamActiveStatus_Codes_tbl].TextVisible, 
[2-01_TeamIDNormalized_tbl].CTeamID
FROM (((([1-01_Clients_tbl] 
LEFT JOIN [1-01-Clients_TransferXtra_tbl] ON [1-01_Clients_tbl].CNR = [1-01-Clients_TransferXtra_tbl].CNR) 
LEFT JOIN _Circular_Temp ON [1-01_Clients_tbl].CNR = [_Circular_Temp].CNR) 
INNER JOIN [5-10_TeamActiveStatus_tbl] ON [1-01_Clients_tbl].CNR = [5-10_TeamActiveStatus_tbl].CNR) 
LEFT JOIN [2-01_TeamIDNormalized_tbl] ON [1-01_Clients_tbl].CNR = [2-01_TeamIDNormalized_tbl].CNR) 
INNER JOIN [5-10_TeamActiveStatus_Codes_tbl] ON [5-10_TeamActiveStatus_tbl].TeamActiveStatusCode = [5-10_TeamActiveStatus_Codes_tbl].TAScodeID
WHERE ((([1-01_Clients_tbl].CNR)<>1 Or ([1-01_Clients_tbl].CNR)=2) 
AND (([_Circular_Temp].ActiveStatus)="yes"));
```

***A) Images of Updatable Query***

*1) The Query*
[image: Design view of the Updatable Query]

*2) Datasheet view of the Query*
[image: Datasheet view of query]

*3) Design view of the form associated with the above query*
[image: The forms(Design view) attached to the query]

*4) The Actual working form*
[image: The actual form in which data can be updated]

**Note that CTeamID(Team column in the form) and Text Visible(Team Active Status column in the form) is missing as these data is derived from two different tables and that's where the issue starts.**

***B) Images of Non-Updatable Query***

*1) The Query*
[image: Non-Updatable Query]

*2) Datasheet view of the Query*
[image: Datasheet view]

*3) The Form*
[image: The Form]

**So here when I added the tables from where we are getting the **CTeamID(Team column in the form)** and **Text Visible(Team Active Status column in the form)** data it's now not updatable query.**

Any ideas or suggestions as to how to make it working or how to improve the query to make it updatable? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Images are not allowed for code data and error messages

Comment: @nbk Sorry for posting only images. I have updated my questions and added both the SQL query's. Thank you.

Comment: The query is too compley and thegenerator makes it worse, maybe make a dbfiddle and build the queries manually adding one table at a time and check the outcome if it fits

Comment: A form should be for input/edit data for only one table. A data entry form should not need such a complex RecordSource - advise you simplify by binding to table. Usually don't need to include lookup tables. If you want to display related info then have expression in textbox refer to combobox columns by index: `=comboboxname.Column(1)`.

Comment: @nbk Thank you for your reply. I will try it on dbfiddle and get back to you.

Comment: @June7 Thank you for your reply. The issue here is that the lookup tables here have data that is not present in the primary table. So, for example, the TeamIDNormalized table contains the TeamID and is linked to the Primary table based on CNR. If I don't add the TeamIDNormalized table in the query, how would I be able to update the TeamID present in the TeamIDNormalized table? Is there any way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not an expert on access but is the whole query non-updateable or just some fields?  You want to update data to multiple sources and are using weird mix of INNER/LEFT JOINs between these tables.  There's some hint of this here: https://rogersaccessblog.blogspot.com/2009/11/this-recordset-is-not-updateable-why.html (a solution to your problem might be point 10: Note: Though you can't update the data in the query directly, you can update the data in a form or data access page based on the query if the form's RecordsetType property is set to Dynaset (Inconsistent Updates).

Comment: Data entry is done via forms and sometimes form/subform arrangements. Your query makes no sense for data entry. Clients table is actually the lookup table as its CNR key is saved into multiple tables. I don't really understand your data schema.

Comment: @siggemannen Thank you for your reply. I tried using the Dynaset(Incosistent Updates) and it worked. I actually read somewhere, it said it could be dangerous to use this feature as it would mess up the data consistency. I'm not sure if I can go ahead with it.

Comment: @June7 Thank you for your reply. Yes, the Client's table is the main table and I agree I can ignore the client's table in the query, but in the form some of the data is present in the client's table and would be need in order to show the result. I'm not sure how other way I can make this working.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like the introduciton of the "inner join" is what blows up this query.

however, I would consider building the query in sql server, and linking as a view.

However, DO KEEP in mind:

Access based tables allow joins and MULTIPLE tables to be updated.

SQL server:

You can have a query (or better a view) that has mutliple tables, but ONLY ONE of the tables can be changed.

In other words, if you edit some columns that belong to MORE then one table, then this is NOT allowed with SQL server tables.

Again:

The view can have multiple tables, but if you edit a column from MORE then one different table, the update does not work with SQL based tables. (it does work with Access based ones).

So, unless you can "disable" some controls on that continues form/datasheet to "limit" or to "ensure" that ONLY ONE BASE table behind will become "dirty", then you can't use that interface. This is a limitation of SQL server, and one that does not (did not) exist when using Access tables as the back end.

SQL server due to transactions, and being ATOMIC does NOT allow a query to have more then one table AND ALSO then udpate in one shot/command.

MS-access tables do allow this!

You can in some cases "kluge" this by using a after update event of the text boxes, and do a me.dirty = false (which forces a write of the record). Since you would be "forcing" a write of the data, then NEVER does more then "one" table in the query get dirty.

So, this is a difference in SQL tables vs Access tables. (only ONE table in the view/query behind can EVER become dirty).

So, by forcing the write of the row data in the text box after update, then you can make this work.

I would thus using a continues form (and not a datasheet) for this purpose (and by continues form, I do mean what is called a multiple-items form.

So, while you can/could/probably get that 2nd query to work (you have to change the inner join to a left join), the NEW issue will be that if you allow editing in that row that will result in more then ONE table becoming dirty, then the update will not work.

So, you either:

Have to be sure ONLY one table behind in that query is ever changed.

Or, do the kluge of adding me.dirty = false in after update of each text box.

or, consider having a button that pops up a form, and only has the columns from one base table behind in that query for allowed edits.

So, just keep in mind that after using up a pot of coffee, and say you REALLY do get that query to become up-dateable?

Keep in mind that rule about ONLY ONE of the tables behind can become dirty at any given time. This means/suggests that while editing could occur in that row, only columns from ONE of the tables behind at a time can become dirty.

So, as noted, I would consider converting that client side query into a view, since that's going to help a WHOLE LOT in operation of that query.

And thus in sql manager, you can then right click on the view, and choose edit. Test it. That way you don't have to go back into ms-access when trying to determine if the query can/does allow updates.

Do keep in mind that you MUST answer the prompt when linking the view to enter the row PK id for access. Keep in mind that if you re-link (point the front end) to a different back end from SQL server? Then the PK row value of the linked view can and will be lost. This issue can be dealt with in a separate question/post, but you do need to keep this additional information in mind.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know and update myself on the difference between how it works on Access and how it works on SQL Server. I will surely implement these and let you know the result. Also, I have a few questions:

Comment: I have a few questions: 1) I want to edit data in 2 different tables i.e the [2-01_TeamIDNormalized_tbl] and [5-10_TeamActiveStatus_tbl]. Can I create a view of the Clients table and join the above two editable tables to the Client's table view? 2) @siggemannen Mentioned that changing to form's RecordsetType property to Dynaset (Inconsistent Updates) works actually, but I'm not sure how good is this method?

Comment: Well, as a general rule, having multiple tables to "see/edit/change/enjoy" as ONE row has ALWAYS been a big problem in ANY database system. For example, HOW are child records that you join in to be added? And if the child table has more then 1 row, your going to now see/get TWO rows in that query, and the user will now see 2 rows - often a HUGE source of confusing. As a general rule, ANY form for editing should be 100% based directly on the ONE table, and the linked table. For any child table of many rows, then use a sub form. And no, introduction of dynaset changes zero in this regards.

Comment: So, a complex number of joins is common for a "display" of such rows, but a edit button on that row to launch a form with sub forms to edit that row is most often how this works. As I noted, with multiple child rows, then you wind up repeating rows of data in the UI - and it not only difficult to edit, but confusing to the user.  So, place a edit button on that row, and launch a whole form to edit. That form can then have sub-forms for the child tables that have repeating rows to the one main parent record. This advice applies to both Access tables and SQL server tables.

Comment: Thank you for your help and advice on how the whole DB works both in SQL and Access. I will definitely keep these information's in mind. However, as per your advice I created a view in SQL Server and linked it back to Access Front-end. It started to work and it is editable. I also created distinct rows from the joined table in sql server using the windows function to only show the latest record that was inserted. It now shows the latest data that was inserted and is editable as well. Thank you once again Albert D. Kallal.

Comment: As noted, the view can be updateable, but if you "dirty" (change) columns from more then one table in that view, then the update will fail. So, you can modify any column, and even several columns. but, if you modify columns from more then one of the tables in the view, then the update is not allowed. As noted, you can kludge your way around this by say in the "last" control of one table, in the after update event put in a me.dirty = false command, and that will then even allow you to edit columns from the several tables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252020/discussion-between-hariharan-iyer-and-albert-d-kallal).